# Using Query to display multiple rows, filtered by person's name

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am trying to get data out of a sheet that is summarizing the answers from a google form. I have the formula below (changed names of references as some data is confidential).

I would ideally do a pivot table, but it needs to be in a different file. I also tried using group by but may have formatted it incorrectly as it just showed #value.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("mysheet", "sheetname!B:CZ"), "Select * where Col3 = 'NAME' ", 1)
```

This is capturing some of the data but displays it in a single row. It also does not capture each row of data from the original sheet where the NAME in column 3 matches the where check.

How can I fix this so that it will display a table similar to the layout of the original, but limited only to the rows where a specific Name has been entered in Col3?

Answer (score 0):

try using `FILTER` like:

```
=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "sheetname!B2:CZ"), 
        IMPORTRANGE("ID", "sheetname!D2:D")="NAME")
```

Comment: Beautiful - Thanks!